# How to include italics in the main heading to my graph?

Tags: r

Here is the code I have atm;

```
plot(V1,V2,pch = 19, main = "Changes in absolute cell volume of Chlorella Alga over a 24hr period", xlab = "Stage in 24hr cycle", ylab = "Absolute cell volume(µm^3)", xlim = c(0,24), ylim = c(32.5,188))
```

I want the `Chlorella` part to be italicized as its the name of an organism. Any thoughts?

Comment: This has nothing to do with RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

use `italic( )`

```
mn <- expression(paste("Changes in absolute cell volume of", italic(" Chlorella "), "Alga over a 24hr period"))

plot(V1,V2,pch = 19, 
     main = mn, 
     xlab = "Stage in 24hr cycle",  
     ylab = "Absolute cell volume(µm^3)",
     xlim = c(0,24), ylim = c(32.5,188))
```